# is there a 'best' class to merge two objects?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two objects together. I have read multiple times that `data.table` is a lot faster than `data.frame` or others.

One object is (in reality with 2000ish rows)

```r
   date    yw    ym
1 17897 17896 17897
2 17898 17896 17897
3 17899 17896 17897
4 17900 17896 17897
5 17901 17896 17897
6 17902 17896 17897
```

and the other would be the unique observations for every (unique) week (month).

I tried different combinations of functions  (`merge()`, `merge.data.frame()` and `merge.data.table()`) with different classes (`data.frame`, `tibble` and `data.table`).

But unlike what I have, read they all operate in the same order of magnitude but `merge()` with plain `data.frame` is consistently the fastest.

So my question is: can improve on  that somehow, or is it only improvable if the dimensions were higher?

Answer (score 2):

Questions that ask for "best" generally are opinion-based and off topic, but here we can run some quick and fast objective numbers to see what's going on.

In general, 2000 rows is relatively "small" compared to some of the big data that R handles. If we look at data of this size, we can see little difference (and these differences would be imperceptible to the user):

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 2e3
df1 <- data.frame(id = seq_len(n),
                  x = runif(n))
df2 <- data.frame(id = seq_len(n),
                  y = runif(n))
dt1 <- data.table::data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table::data.table(df2)
```

Comparison

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  merge_df = merge(df1, df2),
  merge_dt = merge(dt1, dt2),
  mergedt_dt = data.table::merge.data.table(dt1, dt2)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#      expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
# merge_df   888.927 933.6545 1100.3586 1097.9925 1209.938 1576.036   100  a 
# merge_dt   772.873 807.2490  939.9342  955.1305 1030.568 1345.915   100   b
# mergedt_dt 775.424 802.7920 1019.1521  972.9315 1059.108 7279.297   100  ab
```

But if we scale this to one million rows, we do see that data table approaches are about 8 times faster:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e6
df1 <- data.frame(id = seq_len(n),
                  x = runif(n))
df2 <- data.frame(id = seq_len(n),
                  y = runif(n))
dt1 <- data.table::data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table::data.table(df2)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  merge_df = merge(df1, df2),
  merge_dt = merge(dt1, dt2),
  mergedt_dt = data.table::merge.data.table(dt1, dt2)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr        min        lq     mean    median       uq       max neval cld
# merge_df    588.10397 686.30665 799.1511 733.10353 872.3097 1166.3201   100  a 
# merge_dt    72.19061  81.93000 118.8730  90.55916 130.9652  498.8803   100   b
# mergedt_dt  72.87876  83.16898 125.0711  93.59801 136.0912  512.8934   100   b
```

This is because some functions have "overhead" that costs time up front, but then may work much faster.